# SQL Script to generate query from stored description

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data table in the following:

```
Name              Expression
FirstName           NULL
LastName            NULL
FullName          CONCAT(FirstName,LastName)
Gender              NULL
FullNameWGender   CONCAT(FullName,Gender)
```

How do I use SQL statement to produce the following data taken from the table:

```
FirstName, LastName, CONCAT(FirstName,LastName) AS FullName, Gender, CONCAT(CONCAT(FirstName,LastName),Gender) AS FullNameWGender
```

I am using MySQL.

I do not expect a complete code but at least a starting point since I have no idea how to ensure that once I reach the data in expression column that has CONCAT and process it.

Like in the above example, in the table it is `CONCAT(FullName,...)`. But with my SQL, I have to extract that and process it to display as`CONCAT(CONCAT(FirstName,LastName),....)`...

Any help would be great!

Comment: Are you just wanting to select each field of your table? I'm not seeing the problem, would you enlighten me?

Comment: @NappaTheSaiyan, What I wished is to select both column out.
However, for the 'Expression' column, if it is CONCAT(FullName,Gender), when it is selected, it has to check the details within it. In This case, it will check 'FullName' and 'Gender' in the 'Name' column and will check whether each of those field within the column has another CONCAT in their respective 'Expression' column.

Thus, when CONCAT(FullName,Gender) has been selected, it has to display CONCAT(CONCAT(FirstName,LastName),Gender). <= Getting this is something I do not know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have the code in the form of cursor (I have no other choice)

Using the same table as above but with more data:

```
ID    NAME                      EXPRESSION
1      FirstName,                   NULL
2      LastName,                    NULL
3      FullName,                  CONCAT( FirstName, LastName)
4      Gender,                      NULL
5      FullNameWGender,           CONCAT( FullName, Gender)
6      Income,                      NULL
7      Expense,                     NULL
8      Savings,                   ( Income,- Savings,)
9      FullNameWSavings,          CONCAT( FullName, Savings,)
10     Month,                       NULL
11     FullNameWSavingsByMonth,   CONCAT( FullNameWSavings, Month,)
```

To get the updated table as below:

```
ID    Name                      Expression
1      FirstName,                   NULL
2      LastName,                    NULL
3      FullName,                  CONCAT( FirstName, LastName)
4      Gender,                      NULL
5      FullNameWGender,           CONCAT(CONCAT( FirstName, LastName) Gender)
6      Income,                      NULL
7      Expense,                     NULL
8      Savings,                   ( Income,- Savings,)
9      FullNameWSavings,          CONCAT(CONCAT( FirstName, LastName)( Income,-    Savings,))
10     Month,                       NULL
11     FullNameWSavingsByMonth,   CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT( FirstName, LastName)( Income,- Savings,)) Month,)
```

Just for the reference of anyone (hopefully it can be helpful (thanks a lot @Nappa The Saiyan for your answer), the following is the code:

```
DECLARE @id_name INT
DECLARE @id_expression INT
DECLARE @expression NVARCHAR (MAX)
DECLARE @cutExpression NVARCHAR (100)
DECLARE @name NVARCHAR (100)
DECLARE @newExpression NVARCHAR (MAX)
DECLARE @temp NVARCHAR (MAX)

DECLARE @rowNumExp INT
DECLARE @rowNumName INT
DECLARE @rowNum INT
SET @rowNum = 0
SET @rowNumExp = 0
SET @rowNumName = 0

DECLARE expressionList CURSOR FOR
SELECT ID, EXPRESSION FROM table1
OPEN expressionList
FETCH NEXT FROM expressionList
    INTO @id_expression, @expression

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @rowNumExp = @rowNumExp + 1
        IF (@expression IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
            DECLARE nameList CURSOR FOR
            SELET ID, NAME FROM table1
            OPEN nameList
            FETCH NEXT FROM nameList
                INTO @id_name, @name

            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
                IF(CHARINDEX(@name,@expression)>0)
                BEGIN
                    SET @cutExpression = SUBSTRING(@expression,
                                                   CHARINDEX(@name,@expression),
                                                   LEN(@name))
                    SET @temp = (SELECT EXPRESSION FROM table1 WHERE ID = @id_name)
                    IF(@temp IS NOT NULL)
                    BEGIN
                        SET @newExpression = REPLACE (@expression, @name, @temp)
                        UPDATE table1
                            SET EXPRESSION = @newExpression
                            WHERE ID = @id_expression
                        SET @expression = @newExpression

                        CLOSE nameList
                        DEALLOCATE nameList

                        DECLARE nameList CURSOR FOR
                        SELECT ID, NAME FROM table1
                        OPEN nameList
                        FETCH NEXT FROM nameList
                            INTO @id_name, @name
                    END
                END
                SET @rowNumName = @rowNumName + 1
                FETCH NEXT FROM nameList
                    INTO @id_name, @name
            END
            CLOSE nameList
            DEALLOCATE nameList
        END
        FETCH NEXT FROM expressionList
            INTO @id_expression, @expression
END
CLOSE expressionList
DEALLOCATE expressionList
```

Limitations:

1. Starting character for the Name column has to be a space
2. Last character for the Name column has to be a ',' Eg in name column: "
   FirstName," and not "FirstName,"
3. All names in the expression has to be followed by a "," eg in expression column:
   "CONCAT(FullName,Savings,)" and not "CONCAT(FullName,Savings)"

Regardless of the number of "Name" available in the Expression which does not have NULL as its own Expression, the thing will format everything out as the 2nd table above.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do for FullNameWGender is CONCAT(FirstName, LastName, Gender).

```
Select FirstName, LastName, CONCAT(FirstName,LastName) AS FullName, Gender, CONCAT(FirstName, LastName,Gender) AS FullNameWGender
```

CONCAT can be used for more than two strings.
[dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)